# vba Regular Expression Extract 10 Character String That Starts With "B0"

Tags: regex, excel

I'm trying to extract a 10 character string out of the following string:

```
<div class="a-column a-span5 a-span-last"><div class="a-row a-spacing-mini"><span name="B01B5BBNPS">
```

I want to extract B01B5BBNPS. The string will be in Cell "A1". I tried using the following code but it only works when Cell "A1" only contains "B01B5BBNPS".

```
Function CleanString(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "^[B0]{2}[\w]{8}"
    On Error Resume Next
    CleanString = .Execute(strIn)(0)
End With
End Function
```

Comment: Rather use simple string functions, it will be quicker.

Comment: `^` denotes the start of a line, try `.Pattern = "[B0]{2}[\w]{8}"`

Comment: cybernetic.nomad thank you so much. That works like a charm.

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be in regex? Because Excel functions provide much more elegant solution. Or even VBA inbuilt methods library

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad That would also match strings starting with `BB`, `00`,`0B`

Comment: What about a substring like `B01B5BBNPSXXX`?  Do you want the match to fail, or just return the portion that matches?

Comment: I just wanted B01B5BBNPS nothing extra. I adjusted the pattern to [B]{1}[0]{1}[\w]{8}

Comment: @Brett That is the same as `B0\w{8}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern must not begin with the "^" character because it means your pattern will only match string which begin with "B0" (or even 0B, or BB, 00,... nevermind).

You should try this pattern :

```
B0[\w]{8}
```

https://regex101.com/r/zpo3Th/1